# Simple ,complex ,compound

Tags: meaning

Is learning a gerund or it is a kind of noun I am confused plz clear me

The sentence I am confused is

> When Varsha was six , she started learning music .

Here the word started is finite verb and learning is what I am confused **

Answer (score 1):

*"learning music"* is a gerund (-ing) clause, a direct object of the verb *"start"*.